# How to issue some user claims depending on the client?

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server, identityserver5

I would like to be able to issue a phone_number claim xor email claim depending on what is required by the client. I use Identity Server 5(Duende) but the answer will be the same for Identity Server 4.

I understand that I can add a claim to identity token in `ProfileService`, however how to configure the client in the db so I will be able to check what is required by a client in the profile service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional claims should be configured in either `ApiScopeClaims`/`ApiResourceClaims` or `IdentityResourceClaims` depending on if the claim should be include in the access token or the id token (could be both).

For example you if have:

> `IdentityResource` { Id = 1, Name = "profile" }

Then in `IdentityResourceClaims` table you should add:

> `IdentityResourceClaim` { Id = 1, IdentityResourceId = 1, Type = "phone_number" }
> `IdentityResourceClaim` { Id = 2, IdentityResourceId = 1, Type = "email" }

Then when the client requests the `profile` scope, `phone_number` and `email` claim types will be included in `ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes` in the `ProfileService`.

Then inside `ProfileService` you can use `ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes` and `context.AddRequestedClaims` to only add the `Claims` the were requested from the client:

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{
    if (context.RequestedClaimTypes.Any())
    {
        ...

        // create the user claims list
        var claims = CreateClaims(user);

        // this will filter claims list and only add those requested by the client
        context.AddRequestedClaims(claims);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `ClientClaims` not correct table? I think no, but want to be sure, as this is a UserClaim that I want to issue but conditionally, then what you propose `ClientProperties` would be a correct way.

Comment: Updated with better answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, but there is sth I don't understand, how to indicate in the db that a one client wants email but other wants phone_number? It's one xor the other. Because what you are showing seems to be a global config for all the clients that they will always get email and phone, but I want to specify that they can get one xor other.

Comment: In the database you define the client's `AllowedScopes`. Then when the authentication flow happens that client requests some or all of those scopes. Each scope is linked to claims. So if you create a scope that is linked to `phone_number` claim and only allow this scope to a specific client, then only this client will get `phone_number` claim.

Comment: Last question because I can't find it in the docs, I can't see `AllowedScopes` table but I see `ClientScopes` one is this is the one where I define those `AllowedScopes`?

Comment: Yes you should define the scopes in the `ClientScopes` table.